# Getting out of Istanbul airport during 10-15 hours

Tags: istanbul

I am from India & would be transiting Istanbul with a 10-15 hours layover on way from New Delhi to Copenhagen. I would be having a valid Schengen visa.

Can I get out of the airport, or would I require special permissions?

What are the things I can see as a tourist during the 6-8 hours Istanbul visit?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no issue with the visa for Turkey, I guess you can go out.

Assuming it is the Ataturk Airport and that 6-8 hours is on the day-time, maybe you can have the M1A tram from the airport -see the map [here](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.istanbulclues.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F10%2FMetro-Map-of-Istanbul.jpg&f=1).

However, as living in Istanbul, there is no quite near place to see therewards in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to take a separate Turkish visa or does the Schengen visa work for a day time 8 hours tour of Istanbul?